# nodejs: javascript array issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this node.js app which retrieving subway data from mongodb using mongoose, and after I get the data, I will pass it to [sphere-knn](https://github.com/darkskyapp/sphere-knn) to calculate the nearest points. The strange thing happen in `var lookup = sphereKnn(d1);` if I pass `d1` which is hard coded array, the code will work, if I pass the `data` which is retrieved from mongodb, it won't work at all, and returns empty array as result.

`JSON.stringify(data) == JSON.stringify(d1)` will print `true`, `Array.isArray` will also print `true` for both `d1` and `data`, `console.log` will show there are data inside variable `data`.

I'm confused by the behaviour of the code. I came from .net and new to node.js. do I miss any important concept here?

```
mrtStop.find({}, {_id:0}, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    return res.json(err);
  }

  // data returned from mongodb, get first one
  data = data.slice(0,1);

  // hard coded data
  var d1 = [{"id":"EW6",
            "name":"EXAMPLE MRT STATION",
            "lat":1.3210355412,
            "lon":103.9129310102,
            "__v":0}];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(d1));
  // print true
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data) == JSON.stringify(d1));

  // d1 works, but data won't work
  // var lookup = sphereKnn(d1);
  var lookup = sphereKnn(data);

  var points = lookup(req.query.lat, req.query.lon, maxNum);

  res.json(points);
});
```

Comment: Can you show all your log results?

Comment: Have you tried `sphereKnn[data[0]]` ?

Comment: console.log the data and let me know?

Comment: @RahatMahbub that wouldn;'t be the case, OP said d1 == data

Comment: OP used `==` but not `===`. `==` does type conversion. So, i don't know.

Comment: Also, Stringify and the actual data have mismatched for me before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Query.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

**tldr;** *mongoose* returns *mongoose-doc object*, which has many prototypes, when you lean it, it will return *plain js object*

```
//side note: you could also remove `__v` property {_id: 0, __v:0}
mrtStop.find({}, {_id:0}).lean().exec(function(err, data){
  if(err){
    return res.json(err);
  }
  var lookup = sphereKnn(data);
  var points = lookup(req.query.lat, req.query.lon, maxNum);
  res.json(points);
});
```